# Can you write to a socket from disk without loading the data in question into memory first?

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, air, binary

Using the Socket API in AIR to write a large file to a server, is there a way to do this without reading the file into application memory first? I am using FileStream to store the data in a bytearray and then writing that bytearray to the server through the socket but can I just have something like a file descriptor that references that file on the user's disk and have the socket write from there?

Answer (score 0):

Many systems implement [`sendfile(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile). I doubt though you'd have access to it in Flex.